# how to define a function that filters a data frame using another function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have to define a function that selects whoever has sales related job title from a data frame, and it has to include the function below:

```
def isSales(job):
    a = job.lower()
    if 'sales' in a:
        return 'True'
```

Basically it is filtering of a data frame, but the function will go through another function and will include the ones with job titles that has 'sales' in it.

here is a fake dataframe that you can use.

```
employee = {'EmployeeID' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         'FirstName' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
         'LastName' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
         'MiddleName' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i',None]
         'JobTitle : ['Production Supervisor', 'Technician', 'Buyer', 'Sales Manager', 'Data Scientist', 'President', 'Vice President of Sales', 'Manager', 'Stocker', 'Sales Accountant'}

employee_df = pd.DataFrame(employee)
```

after I define it, I have to check with this code and see if it works properly

```
sales_df = filterSales(employees_df)
print "Number of rows: %d\nNumber of cols: %d\n" % (sales_df.shape[0], sales_df.shape[1])
print "Head of index: %s\n" % (sales_df.index[:10])
print "Record of sales employee with ID=280\n"
print sales_df.loc[280]
```

Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print (employee_df[employee_df['JobTitle'].str.lower().str.contains('sales')])
   EmployeeID FirstName                 JobTitle LastName MiddleName
3           3         d            Sales Manager        d          d
6           6         g  Vice President of Sales        g          g
9           9         j         Sales Accountant        j       None
```

Also is possible create function, where `job` is column name

```
def isSales(job):
    return employee_df[employee_df[job].str.lower().str.contains('sales')]

print (isSales('JobTitle'))
   EmployeeID FirstName                 JobTitle LastName MiddleName
3           3         d            Sales Manager        d          d
6           6         g  Vice President of Sales        g          g
9           9         j         Sales Accountant        j       None
```

If input is `DataFrame` and need all columns and all rows contains `sales`:

```
def isSales(df):
    bool_df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower().str.contains('sales'))
    return df.loc[bool_df.any(axis=1), bool_df.any()]
    #for return all columns
    #return df[bool_df.any(axis=1)]

print (isSales(employee_df))
                  JobTitle
3            Sales Manager
6  Vice President of Sales
9         Sales Accountant
```

---

If need use your function and create another for filtering use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for working with each element in `DataFrame` for return `boolean DataFrame`. Last for all rows with `sales` in any column use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

But your function `isSales` failed, if some `NaN`s in data.

```
def isSales(job):
    a = str(job).lower()
    if 'sales' in a:
        return True

def filterSales(df):
    bool_df = df.applymap(isSales)
    return df[bool_df.any(axis=1)]

sales_df = filterSales(employee_df)
print (sales_df)
   EmployeeID FirstName                 JobTitle LastName MiddleName
3           3         d            Sales Manager        d          d
6           6         g  Vice President of Sales        g          g
9           9         j         Sales Accountant        j       None
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, but if I run your code with the checking code that I just edited, it gives me error saying "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'"

Comment: Maybe there is problem no rows are returned?

Comment: But can you add your another function to question? Because if need return boolean maybe need change only `return 'True'` to `return True` for return boolean, not string True.

Comment: I took the last set of code and tried to run but it gives me this error.

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: filterSales(employees_df)

Comment: I define the function and tried to run the function and that error comes out

Comment: Hmmm, is not possible use first or second solution? Because maybe problem in `a = str(job)` - but hard to know, becasue it depends of your data.